# Subspace Proof when $f(x)=0$ or has degree $n$

Tags: real-analysis

Is the set $W=\{f(x) \in P(F): f(x)=0 \text{ or } f(x) \text{ has degree n}\}$ a subspace of $P(F)$ if $n\geq 1$?

I know that three conditions must exist in order for $W$ to be a subspace: the zero vector must exist, it must be closed under addition, and closed under scalar multiplication. I know how to do this for problems that actually give a function, but not ones more abstract. Any suggestions on how specifically to show the latter two conditions?

Comment: What's $(x^n)+(-x^n+1)$? Is it in $W$?

Comment: I believe so...  (xn)+(−xn+1)=1 which is in W, but would this prove its closed under addition?

Comment: $1$ has degree $0 < n$. So $W$ is not closed under addition, and is therefore not a subspace.

Comment: Ok that makes sense...thank you!!